# Slideshow using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a slideshow created by jQuery which slides from left to right by default. There is a next button which on click should slide the images from left to right and while clicking the previous button the images should slide from right to left.

Currently I have a code like :

```
jQuery('.slider').cycle({ 
      fx:     'scrollRight', 
      speed:  1000, 
      timeout:5000, 
      next:   '.next',
      prev:  '.prev'
    });
```

Now it slides from right to left by default and on clicking the next button as required, but
**it has to move from left to right on previous button clicking which is not happening..**

I will be really thankfull if any body can help in this matter..

**EDIT:** 
here is the html code:

```
<div class="slider ddblock-processed" style="position: relative; width: 990px; height: 396px; visibility: visible; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">
         <div class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 1; width: 990px; height: 396px; z-index: 4; left: 990px; display: none; "><img src="http://files/images/ddblock/mobile-apps.png" alt="image" style="height: 392px; width: 990px; " class="ddblock-processed"></div>
         <div class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 1; width: 990px; height: 396px; z-index: 4; left: 990px; display: none; "><img src="http://files/images/ddblock/seo.png" alt="image" style="height: 392px; width: 990px; " class="ddblock-processed"></div>
         <div class="slide" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5; top: 0px; opacity: 1; display: block; width: 990px; height: 396px; left: 0px; "><img src="http://files/images/ddblock/web-applications.png" alt="image" style="height: 392px; width: 990px; " class="ddblock-processed"></div>
         <div class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 1; width: 990px; height: 396px; z-index: 4; left: 990px; display: none; "><img src="http://files/images/ddblock/webdesign.png" alt="image" style="height: 392px; width: 990px; " class="ddblock-processed"></div>
       </div>
 <!-- prev/next pager on slide -->
       <div class="pager-slide prev-container prev-container-top">
   <a class="prev" href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="pager-slide next-container next-container-top">
   <a class="next" href="#"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: We need some more code to help you solve this? show us the cycle code.

Comment: show us a little html there neeraja.

Comment: We need to see the javascript you've created, else we can't help

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HTML5Slides](http://code.google.com/p/html5slides/), a free solution provided by Google.